# How to access rootValue or context for nodedefination

Tags: relayjs

We could check rootValue or context to determine request's role permission for graphql request.
How do we check permission for nodeDefination (request thru 'node' ) when using graphql-relay-js ?

Comment: What do you mean by "request thru 'node' "? Can you please give an example to better understand your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access your permissions with either `context` or a value from `rootValue`, as both are made available to the resolver function:

```
export const {nodeField, nodeInterface} = nodeDefinitions(
  function resolveObjectFromID(globalId, context, {rootValue}) {
    const {type, id} = fromGlobalId(globalId);

    // Optionally perform auth logic here with either context or rootValue...

    // Then proceed with loading as usually; here, for example, using
    // DataLoader.
    const loader = rootValue.loaders[type];
    return (loader && loader.load(id)) || null;
  },
  function resolveGraphQLTypeFromObject(object) {
    return registeredTypes[object.constructor.name] || null;
  },
);
```

Note that the `context` param was added in graphql v0.5.0; prior to that you could only use `rootValue`. Also note that you can perform permission checks at any level within in the query, not just at the `node` level, because `context` and `rootValue` both get propagated down all the way.